# Node.js: Typing error: Notes.addNote is not a function

Tags: node.js

Following a tutorial on Node.js, get an error.

> app.js:

```
console.log('Starting app.js');

const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require ('lodash');
const yargs = require('yargs');

const notes = require ('./notes.js');

const argv = yargs.argv;

var command = process.argv[2];
console.log ('Command:' , command);
console.log ('Process: ', process.argv);
console.log('Yargs: ', argv)
if (command === 'add') {
  notes.addNote (argv.title, argv.body);
}
else if (command === 'list') {
  notes.getAll();
}
else if (command === 'read') {
  notes.readNote(argv.title);
}
else if (command === 'delete') {
  console.log ('command deleted');
}
else {
  console.log('command not recognized');
}
```

> notes.js:

```
console.log('Starting notes.js');

var addNote = function (title, body) {
  console.log ('Adding note', title, body);
};

var getAll =() => {
  console.log ("getting all notes");
};

var readNote = function(title) {
  console.log("I am reading note", title);
}

module.export = {
  addNote,
  getAll,
  readNote
};
```

I get the error that variables `addNote`, `getAll` and `readNote` are not a function. To me it looks like variables from `app.js` are not being read from `notes.js`. But the `"Starting notes.js"` is actually being read and printed.
What could be the problem here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo.
It should be [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

```
module.exports = {
    addNote,
    getAll,
    readNote
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The thing is I too got the Same Typo,Thanks